# Find Number of Nodes which have Links NetworkX

Tags: graph, hyperlink, nodes, networkx

suppose i have a graph that looks like this:

[image: Graph]

Is there any possible way to only count nodes that have links? So instead of 6, it counts 5, since there is one node that doesn't have link.

Also, if I open a graph with read_edgelist, and afterwards use number_of_nodes function, is the function counts all nodes whether those have links or not or only those which has links/edges, since I opened it with read_edgelist? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter out single nodes, you can iterate through graph nodes and keep only nodes that have neighbors.

With generator:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(40, 0.05, directed=False, seed=1)
print([n for n in G.nodes if len(list(G.neighbors(n))) > 0])
```

or `filter` function:

`print(list(filter(lambda n: len(list(G.neighbors(n))) > 0, G.nodes)))`

Both will print the same:

> `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39]`

---

If I understand the second part correctly, networkx returns you the number of all nodes in the graph, not only that have edges.